# Can a user login without a client-id as in the test case in Spring Authorization Server sample project?

Tags: spring-authorization-server

I am curious about this login step in the test case in Spring Authorization Server defaultAuthorizationServer [sample project test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/88d604f6a45182bc6fd15cc1d5592ebb9b292d69/samples/default-authorizationserver/src/test/java/sample/DefaultAuthorizationServerApplicationTests.java#L104) that does not have a client-id associated but the user can still login:

```
@Test
    public void whenLoggingInAndRequestingTokenThenRedirectsToClientApplication() throws IOException {
        // Log in
        this.webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        this.webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(false);
        signIn(this.webClient.getPage("/login"), "user1", "password");

        // Request token
        WebResponse response = this.webClient.getPage(AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST).getWebResponse();

        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY.value());
        String location = response.getResponseHeaderValue("location");
        assertThat(location).startsWith(REDIRECT_URI);
        assertThat(location).contains("code=");
    }
```

I ran this test case in my project.  I have a AuthenticationProvider implementation and I checked for the clientId and it is null based on the RequestCache. Will there be a case where the user can login to Authorization server without a client id?  My thoughts are that there will always be a client app or client-id associated when a user logs in to the login page.

The following is my AuthenticationProvider implementation:

```
@Service
public class AuthenticationCallout implements AuthenticationProvider {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationCallout.class);

    private RequestCache requestCache;
    private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;


    public AuthenticationCallout(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder, RequestCache requestCache) {
        this.webClientBuilder = webClientBuilder;
        this.requestCache = requestCache;
    }


    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        LOG.info("authenticate with username and password");

        final String clientId = ClientIdUtil.getClientId(requestCache);
        LOG.info("clientId: {}", clientId);  //client-id is always null because the login does not have a client association
...
}

//ClientIdUtil implmentation
public class ClientIdUtil {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientIdUtil.class);

    public static String getClientId(RequestCache requestCache) {
        var requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        var request = requestAttributes.getRequest();
        var response = requestAttributes.getResponse();
        var savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);
        return ClientIdUtil.getParameter(savedRequest, OAuth2ParameterNames.CLIENT_ID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user initiates authorization from the client (via a redirect to log in or to authorize a client), there will be a request in the `RequestCache`. However, the authorization server is still just a normal application, with its own login. So a user can (and in more advanced authorization server deployments, will) log directly into the authorization server.

Imagine a scenario where the user forgot their password, so they click "Forgot Password" on a desktop, and have an email sent to them. They click a link in the email on their phone to reset the password, and log in successfully on their phone afterwards. There will be no request in the `RequestCache`. There are many other scenarios where a user would log in first (e.g. to update their profile, password, security options, visit a dashboard, etc.).

In the test case, it is indeed the case that the user logs in first, and **then** goes through the authorization code flow.

Comment: I would argue/think that the reset password functionality is a another domain where the user is resetting their password which could be handled by a user service for example.  That reset password would not use or need a client-id in that case.  I think I understand that piece and ofcourse it depends on each use case too.  But I am ok with your explanation.

Comment: Agreed, there's a lot of different ways to set things up depending on use case, such as with a multi-tenant app etc.